# PostgreSQL: Removing duplicate column

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I am working on the output of a postgres subquery and have the table with 20 columns(generated using WITH clause).

The table looks something like this

```
col1    col2    col3     --- col20
 4        4       24
 6        6       45
 5        5       66
 5        5       12
```

I want to write a write a query that remove the duplicated column. I tried by select all the columns except the 2nd. But I could not find a better way to do that.

The expected output is:

```
col1           col3   ------ col20
 4              24
 6              45
 5              66
 5              12
```

Thanks

Comment: Just: `select col1, col2 from mytable`?

Comment: `col1 and col2' are part of a single table?

Comment: I have 20 more columns. I should have written it in the question. I will update that.

Comment: perhaps like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947581/select-all-columns-except-for-some-postgresql

Comment: Just list the columns you want, that after all is the way SQL is designed after all so there basically is no better way. The other option would to just remove the column you don't want from the CTE (with clause).